# How to increment value from table in php

Tags: php, mysql

See like here is a Table named play .

Name ,  Key , count
ball , 02322,  002
bad , 00121,  008
bin ,91123, 001

like you can see the count evry time when any key runs i have to count it in there so in that case i have to read the current value and then add and update it to the table . is ther any easier ways ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an [`UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html) query for that. It's usually something like:

```
 db("UPDATE `play` SET count=(count+1) WHERE key=?", $key);
```

The `SET` clause allows to use an expression to be assigned to the column.