# Incrementing values within a PHP generated HTML table by looping a JSON array

Tags: php, arrays, json, html-table

I have an HTML table the `<tr><th><td>` part of which is generated by PHP and the `<body><tbody>` and `<tfoot>` I set manually within the HTML without a PHP loop. The PHP loop creating the table cells is looping over a 3-level deep multidimensional JSON array. I don't have trouble understanding the array and accessing the values within it.

My trouble starts with the fact that there might sometimes be two entries or more for the same day. In such a case, I want the value to be added to the cell containing the work hours of the employee for the respective date. I wondered, is there any way I can address a particular HTML table cell with PHP? Or is there someway to make the cell itself contain a PHP variable that then receives the value dynamically?

I have researched a bit the other questions asked on related topics, nevertheless none of them gave me a hint on how to solve my issue.

The user @ASR here gives a relatively satisfying answer here, nonetheless it is by querying a MySQL database which is much different than looping a JSON array:
[how to increment values inside a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30316231/how-to-increment-values-inside-a-table)

Here again one more question regarding MySQL:
[How to increment value from table in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7775121/how-to-increment-value-from-table-in-php)

And a somehow similar question but about outnumbering rows and again address the SQL question, which is not my case. [How to dynamic continues increase the number of html table in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32065207/how-to-dynamic-continues-increase-the-number-of-html-table-in-php)

To sum-up, my question in short is:

How do I dynamically create an HTML table, from a JSON array, using PHP? The table cells would then contain variables which values can later dynamically get incremented like a regular variable, e.g. $incrVal += 1;

And also an important question is, how do I do that without the need to draw the table from scratch?

My code:

```
    <body>
<table class="styled-table">
    <tbody>
<?php
$date = '2014-08-01'; # On iteration only the start date should be changed
$toConvert = new DateTime($date);
$month = $toConvert->format('m');
$year = $toConvert->format('y'); 
$daysInMonth = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month , $year);
$month = $toConvert->format('M');
$year = $toConvert->format('Y'); 
echo "<p>There were $daysInMonth days in the month $month of the year $year</p>\n";
$month = $toConvert->format('m');
$year = $toConvert->format('Y');
$startDate = $date;
$numDays = intval($daysInMonth);
$numDays1 = strval($numDays);
$strtotimeDaysParam = '+'. strval($numDays) . ' day';
$endDate = strtotime($startDate . $strtotimeDaysParam);
$endDate = $year . '-' . $month . '-' . $numDays1;
echo "<p>END DATE IS $endDate</p>\n";
$wDayNumDayConcatenated = '';
$weekOccurenceConcatenated = ''; 
$counter = 0;
$weekNumber = date("W", strtotime($date));
$nextWeekNumber = intval($weekNumber) + 1; 
$weekNumberList = [];
while ($date <= $endDate) 
{ 
  $weekNumber = intval(date("W", strtotime($date)));

  array_push($weekNumberList, $weekNumber);
 
  $date1 = new DateTime($date);
  $date=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date . ' +1 day' ));
  $nextWeekNumber = intval($weekNumber) + 1; 
  $wDayNumDayConcatenated .= '<th><p class="wday">' . strval($date1->format('D')) . '</p>' . '<p class="numday">'  . strval(intval($date1->format('d'))) . '</p></th>';
  # TO DO: Gather all the dates of interest in one array.
}

$setWeeks = array_unique($weekNumberList);

foreach ($setWeeks as $itemWeek){
    #echo 'I am counting weeks occurences of week in an array: ';
    $weekOccCounter = count(array_keys($weekNumberList, $itemWeek));
    $weekOccurenceConcatenated .= '<th colspan="' . $weekOccCounter . '">WK ' . $itemWeek . '</th>';
}

echo '<tr><th rowspan="2">Employee</th>' . $weekOccurenceConcatenated . '<th rowspan="2">Totals: </th></tr>';
echo '<tr>' . $wDayNumDayConcatenated . '</tr>';

$json = 
'
[{
    "employeeNo": 220,
    "displayName": "Koller",
    "hours": [{
        "date": "2022-01-01",
        "hour": 4,
        "bonus": "12€",
        "icon": "hospital"
    }, {
        "date": "2022-01-01",
        "hour": 4,
        "bonus": "12€",
        "icon": "work"
    }, {
        "date": "2022-01-03",
        "hour": 4,
        "bonus": "12€",
        "icon": "work"
    }]
}, {
    "employeeNo": 660,
    "displayName": "Jameson",
    "hours": [{
        "date": "2022-01-01",
        "hour": 2,
        "bonus": "5€",
        "icon": "hospital"
    }, {
        "date": "2022-01-01",
        "hour": 1,
        "bonus": "20€",
        "icon": "work"
    }, {
        "date": "2022-01-03",
        "hour": 4,
        "bonus": "12€",
        "icon": "work"
    }]
},
{
    "employeeNo": 110,
    "displayName": "Hagen",
    "hours": [{
        "date": "2022-01-01",
        "hour": 2,
        "bonus": "5€",
        "icon": "hospital"
    }, {
        "date": "2022-01-01",
        "hour": 1,
        "bonus": "20€",
        "icon": "work"
    }, {
        "date": "2022-01-03",
        "hour": 4,
        "bonus": "12€",
        "icon": "work"
    }
    ]
}
]
';
$echo1 = $json[0][0];
$echo2 = json_decode($json, true);
$echo3 = 'Emoployee Number: ' . $echo2[0]['employeeNo'];
$echo4 = ' Hours: ' . $echo2[0]['hours'][0]['hour'];
$employeeName = ' Name: ' . $echo2[0]['displayName'];
$echo6 = ' Bonus: ' . $echo2[0]['hours'][0]['bonus'];
$echo7 = ' Icon: ' . $echo2[0]['hours'][0]['icon'];
$echo8 = ' Date: ' . $echo2[0]['hours'][0]['date'];

#echo $echo3;
#echo $echo4;
#echo $employeeName;
#echo $echo6;
#echo $echo7;
#echo $echo8;

foreach($echo2 as $item => $itemized){
  $employeeName = $itemized['displayName'];
  echo '<tr>' . '<td>' . ($itemized['employeeNo']) . '<br>' . $employeeName . '</td>';

  foreach($itemized['hours'] as $entry => $hoursEntry){
    echo '<td>' . $hoursEntry['hour'] . '</td>';
    // $arrDate = $hoursEntry['date'];

    // if ($arrDate == $currentDate){
    //   $hoursSum += $hoursEntry['hour'];
    // }
    // else {
    //   $hoursSum = $hoursEntry['hour'];
    // }
    #echo '<td>' . $hoursEntry['hour'] . '</td>';
    }   
    #echo '<td>' . $hoursSum . '</td>';
    echo '<td> <div id="container">
    <table class="blueTable">
      <tbody class="blueTable">
        <tr class="blueTable">
          <td class="iconsclass">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-h"></i>
          </td>
          <td class="hoursclass">

            7.00 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="blueTable">
          <td class="iconsclass">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-house-chimney"></i>
          </td>
          <td class="hoursclass">

            7.00
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="iconsclass">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-table"></i>
          </td>
          <td class="hoursclass">
            7.00 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="blueTable">
          <td class="iconsclass"><i class="fa-solid fa-gears">
            </i>
          </td>
          <td class="hoursclass">7.00
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="blueTable">
          <td class="iconsclass">Total:</td>
          <td class="hoursclass">7.00</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>

    </table>
  </div></td>';

echo '</tr>';
}

?>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: Separation of concerns would help the code quality a lot. If you're not familiar with the model-view-controller pattern, it's worth looking into. Basically instead of doing a bunch of echoing, instead populate an array and send it to the view which would be responsible for taking an array and displaying it within the HTML. The controller would be responsible for accepting the start date, and perhaps the end date or calculating it dynamically as well as communicating with the model and the view. The model would basically contain your JSON along with manipulations.

Comment: Note I'm using these terms quite loosely. There's many MVC variants out there. But the main thing they all strive to achieve is separation of concerns.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72685512/edit) to show an example of the intended final HTML output from the given JSON.